# nodejs proxy timing and async behavior

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I have a question about the code below:
I would need a confirmation that all the processing done in proxyRes event
will be done asynchronously and all processing time in it won't affect
the proxying time.

Thank you in advance for help in this

```
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.time();
    var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
    proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: 'https://gdev.sserver.be/api/host1/account',
    });
    console.timeEnd();

    proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        //console.log('RAW Response from the target', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
        proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('resp => ' + chunk);
                connection.query('INSERT INTO test SET ?', {content: chunk}, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('writing in db');
                });
        });
        proxy.close();
        proxy = null;
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the contents of your proxyRes handler appear to be asynchronous. The proxy will occur while the database query is still doing what it needs to do, so you're right that it won't affect proxying time.